# Calculating charging/discharging curves of a RC circuit by integration

Tags: python, scipy, physics, differential-equations

I'm trying to calculate the charging and discharging of a RC circuit by integrating a differential equation.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def equa_diff(E, tab_t, tau, t):
    return E/(R*C)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor="#FFFFCC")
cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='blue', linewidth=1)

#Les paramètres physiques
E = 5
R = 1000.0
C = 1e-6
tau = R * C
u0 = 0
cond_init = [0, E / R]

#Les paramètres numériques
t_min = 0.0
t_max = 10e-3
n_t = 100
tab_t = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, n_t)
tab_t1 = tab_t + 0.01
tab_u = odeint(equa_diff, u0, tab_t, args=(tau, E))
tab_u1 = odeint(equa_diff, E, tab_t1, args=(tau, 0))
u_max = max(tab_u)

#La charge du condensateur
ax.plot(tab_t, tab_u, 'r', label='uc(t)')
ax.plot(tab_t, np.ones(100) * E, 'black', label='e(t)')
ax.plot(tab_t, tab_t / tau, 'b', label="tangente à l'origine")
ax.plot(tab_t, -tab_u + E, 'green', label='ur(t)')

#La décharge du condensateur
ax.plot(tab_t1, tab_u1, 'r')
ax.plot(tab_t1, np.zeros(100), 'black')
ax.plot(tab_t1, -tab_u1 + E, 'green')

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.title('Circuit en série RC')
plt.ylim(0, u_max * 1.2)
plt.legend(loc=4)

plt.show()
```

I would like to have this:

[image: I would like to have this]

But I have this:

[image: But I have this]

I've tried my best, but I couldn't manage to correct it.

Comment: In other words, you have no difficulty in drawing the curves, but in calculating the correct values.

Comment: Yes, I have some problems with this chapter... I have some issues finding the correct differential equation...  I don't even know where I am wrong...

Comment: If you need some help with the equations, this [PDF](https://aplusphysics.com/courses/ap-c/tutorials/APC-Circuits.pdf) (page 6 in particular) has the math to solve the differential equations and then you can manually program those functions instead. If you still need any help, please let me know!

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ! But I am supposed to solve my differential equation with the function "odeint", and I really don't understand how it works. Here is my equation : dUc/dt + Uc/RC = E/RC. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You must take into account that charging and discharging are described by

charging

```
dUc/dt + Uc/RC = E/RC => dUc / dt = 1/RC * ( E - Uc)
```

discharging

```
dUc/dt + Uc/RC = 0 => dUc / dt = -Uc/RC
```

Your function is missing the `-Uc/RC`, you can keep it as one function in python if you wish, but I split it into a charging and discharging form out of personal preference. I also had to modify your tangent line at t=0 for the charging process, as it wasn't giving me the correct slope.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Les paramètres physiques
E = 5
R = 1000.0
C = 1e-6
tau = R * C
u0 = 0

def RC_Circuit_Charging(u, t):
    return (E - u )/(R*C)
    
def RC_Circuit_Discharging(u, t):
    return -u/(R*C)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor="#FFFFCC")
cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='blue', linewidth=1)

#Les paramètres numériques
t_min = 0.0
t_max = 10e-3
n_t = 100
tab_t = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, n_t)
tab_t1 = tab_t + 0.01
tab_u = odeint(RC_Circuit_Charging, u0, tab_t)
tab_u1 = odeint(RC_Circuit_Discharging, E, tab_t1)
u_max = max(tab_u)

#La charge du condensateur
ax.plot(tab_t, tab_u, 'r', label='uc(t)')
ax.plot(tab_t, np.ones(100) * E, 'black', label='e(t)')
ax.plot(tab_t, E * tab_t / tau, 'b', label="tangente à l'origine") # tangent line du/dt at t = 0  so E - u(0) / RC = E / RC
ax.plot(tab_t, -tab_u + E, 'green', label='ur(t)')

#La décharge du condensateur
ax.plot(tab_t1, tab_u1, 'r')
ax.plot(tab_t1, np.zeros(100), 'black')
ax.plot(tab_t1, -tab_u1 + E, 'green')

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('u')
plt.title('Circuit en série RC')
plt.ylim(0, u_max * 1.2)
plt.legend(loc=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]